# iphone categorization problem

Tags: iphone, view, categorization

I'll make a simple app with these features;

In main windows there will be a menu.

```
Menu Item 1
Menu Item 2
Menu Item 3
```

When user click Menu Item 1

a new menu based view should appear, however when user clicked menu item 2, a text based view should appear.

I made a navigation based app, but i couldn't connect different view file for each cell.

How can i do this ? Have you got any example ?

My app:

```
Menu Item 1
- Menu Item 1.1
- Text
- Menu Item 1.2
- Menu Item 1.2.1
- Text
- Menu Item 1.2.2
- Text
Menu Item 2
- Text

...
..
.
```

(probably i will use sqlite for context of menu and texts.)

Comment: Please ask a concrete question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

and the associated sample code, this is a good one.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WorldCities/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009466